# @RequestBody or @ModelAttribute with Spring+REST web services

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am creating a Restful website and Web services for iPhone and android apps with **Spring 3.1**. In my application, i am using Spring Message Convertors (`org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`) to converting JSON into Java object and vice-versa.

> My objective is that there should be only single controller
>   method(same URL) that should be used by JSP page, Iphone/Andois app.

I am using **Spring form tag** for object binding from JSP to controller with the help of `@ModelAttribute` like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "reset-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView resetPassword(@ModelAttributeForgot forgotPassword,
     HttpServletRequest request) { 

     System.out.println("data recived=="+forgotPassword.getNewPassword());
 }
```

But the same is NOT working in the case if the data is being posted from iPhone/Android app and the result is:

> data recived==null;

So to overcome this problem i have used `@RequestBody` annotation at place of `@ModelAttribute`.

So my controller looks like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "reset-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView resetPassword(@RequestBody Forgot forgotPassword,
    HttpServletRequest request) { 

    System.out.println("data recived=="+forgotPassword.getNewPassword());
}
```

It works then and the result i got is:

> data recived==somedata;

But @RequestBody then doesn't work with spring form on JSP page and the data doesn't get converted into object and i got `null` values.

1. Can't i use `@RequestBody` annotation to post data in form of JSON
   with spring form tag from JSP page??
2. Is there any way by using which i can post data from my JSP form as
   well as from I phone App by using only a single controller method(either @ModelAttribute or @RequestBody).

**EDIT:**

While writing `String` in place of Bean class, i am able to get the content in form of plain text, as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "reset-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView resetPassword(@RequestBody String string,
     HttpServletRequest request) { }
```

**Result from web page call:**

> uid=11&confirmPassword=somepassword&newPassword=somepassword

**Result from iPhone using web service call(in **JSON**)**

```
{"newPassword":"somepassword","confirmPassword":"somepassword","uid":"11"}
```

But problem is that using this approach i have to parse the JSON string into Java object manually. And in web page content i have to find the values manually that i don't want.

Please help.

Regards,

Arun Kumar

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I don't believe there is a way, because @ModelAttribute is bound from form post parameters and @RequestBody passes the body straight to the Json converter. You could replace the spring form tag with a simple json post, but that is probably less convenient than having two @RequestMapping methods.

Answer (score 0):

Its @RequestBody. I feel its better to specify the mime type that you are expecting and producing as output using @RequestMapping as,

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/authenticate",produces="application/json",   
consumes="application/json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Then register appropriate message converters with [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html#setMessageConverters%28org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter%5b%5d%29)

This message converter is responsible for Marshalling & unmarshalling of your request & response entity based on produces & consumes attributes.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" >
     <property name="order" value="1" />
         <property name="messageConverters">
         <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" >

                 <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
         </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: depreciated now. no need for handler now