# Spring Data JPA : How save data into database using save() of jpaRepository

Tags: postgresql, save, spring-data-jpa

I created one spring Application.  I am trying to save data into database using save method of JPA Repository. i am getting Error `null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

HomeController

```
@RestController
public class HomeController
{    
    @Autowired
    public userRepository repository;

     @RequestMapping(value="/save2",method=RequestMethod.POST )
     public String save1(@ModelAttribute user us)
     {

         repository.save(us);

       return "sucessfull";

     }
}
```

user

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user", schema="new")
public class user implements Serializable 
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2956665320311624925L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer id;

@Column(name="uname")
public String uname;

@Column(name="pass")
public String pass;
```

Table Script

[image]

[image]

Through Postman I am trying to Insert following data

[image]

I am getting this error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Can Any one tell me what i am doing wrong in above code

Comment: why are you creating id when you have `GenerationType.IDENTITY`

Comment: I am not understanding. what you are saying .no need to create id filed in model

Comment: Don't pass id field in the json

Comment: I tried that also. same error comming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see couple of issues here.

First, replace your `@ModelAttribute` with `@RequestBody` since you're sending a JSON request, it is wise to use the latter. (Read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824012/spring-modelattribute-vs-requestbody) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229584/requestbody-or-modelattribute-with-springrest-web-services)). In your case, the values from request is not passed to repository `save` method including `Id` value. That's the reason you're getting not null constraint error.

Second, since you're using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy, you should use `serial` or `bigserial` type to let Postgres to generate your primary key.

Read up nicely written answers on `IDENTITY` strategy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603638/what-is-the-use-of-annotations-id-and-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype)

Answer (score 0):

You defined `id` as an `Integer` field in your model class. Try to pass the value in the json as an `Integer`, not as a `String`.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "uname": "abc",
    "upass": "abc"
}
```